# Testing jvectormap.com in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jvectormap

Currently I'm developing a web page sing the plug-in `"JVectorMap"`.

I'm using the latest version, which you can find [here](http://jvectormap.com/download):

It works fine on FireFox, Chrome and also IE9 and IE10.

**My issue**

Nevertheless, I need it to **work** on **IE8** and I just can't make it work! It just shows me a blank page on the monitor and in all the other browsers, they show me the entire map with the desired characteristics.

Does someone have experienced something similar or have a guess?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery Vector map Forums

Accepter Answer on forums.

> Don't use the minimized vmap file "jquery.vmap.min.js" - it's corrupt or something. If you use the regular "jquery.vmap.js" file the maps should work fine in IE8. Was having the same issue where the map was just a blue box, or not rendering at all. Using the non-minimized file fixed it.

**Solution 1**

so just change the regular file `jquery.vmap.js`

**Solution 2**

removing the if sentence at line 467 of the JS file:

```
if (!regionClickEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {}
```

**Solution 3**

In the source file "jquery.vmap.js", you can replace some `"coords.join(',')"`

by the following basic code:

```
coords[0] + ',' + coords[1]
```

Comment: I downloaded the following: jquery.vmap.js",
  jquery.vmap.world.js",jquery.vmap.sampledata.js",jqvmap.css" but still shows me blank with IE8. Could it be something with settings at IE8??

Comment: I tried to run this page in IE8. http://jqvmap.com/ But no maps are displayed. Any suggestions??

Comment: Thanks Added it but still no change.

Comment: Well @Gayathri, thats a weird issue, did you take a look on forums?

Comment: @Gayathri you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I might have a workaround/hack which could lead someone to an actual fix, I accidentally found out that this issue disappears if  I edit the HTML inside IE developer tools. So i used a function with a timeout which detaches the map html and then attaches it back to the page. But the map then lost its background colors, so i also had to manually trigger hover events for the individual regions as well.

```
function RefreshMap(){
     var html= $('#map1').detach(); 
     $('#mapContainer2').append(html);
     $('.jvectormap-region').trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseout');
}
setTimeout(RefreshMap,1000);
```